# Set expiry time of Downloadable Product Link

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In magento admin panel, I can limit the number of downloads for a downloadable product.

But I want to set expiry time of Downloadable Product Link. 

and also which user receives in Mail after purchase of product ?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Not yet !! If you find any answer please let me know... @ravisoni

Comment: This question should be moved to magento.stackexchange.com as there will get more help. I have the same question and I was thinking not to ask again.